# Probability of random population value being higher than sample maximum

Tags: probability, hypothesis-testing, mathematical-statistics, extreme-value

Considering a small sample size (*n* < 10) from a population, I'm trying to find **how likely a random population value would be *greater* than the maximum of the sample**.

Hoping ye could help me with this! I figure it's the kind of thing that's difficult to google, but that seasoned statisticians would know off the bat.

I've looked into Z- and t-statistics, which seem adjacent to what I need, but concerning means instead of arbitrary values or maxima. I'm aware the confidence brackets are going to be terrible for that kind of sample size, but it would be great at least as a proof-of-concept for my research.

Although I'm really enjoying learning about it, I'm still a newcomer to statistics, so bear with me here :)

Comment: Hint: in the set of values comprised of the sample and the random population value, the assumptions of independent observations of identically distributed variables imply every one of those values has an equal chance of being the largest.  Apply this result to the random population value.  Bear in mind that the answer depends on the nature of the common distribution: if it has any discrete component, there will be the possibility of a *tie* for the largest and you will have to account for that.  Google "nonparametric prediction limit" for theory and references.